# Error while sending image and json data in one request in angular 8

Tags: angular, http-headers, http-post, angular8

I am trying to send image and some json data in one http post request. 
Header is

```
this.httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
}
```

and my html part is

```
<input #imageInput type="file" name="add-logo" accept="image/*"
    id="add-logo" (change)="onFileChanged(imageInput)" class="form-control cust-field" placeholder="">
```

and component.ts function is

```
    logo:File
  onFileChanged(imageInput: any) {
      const file: File = imageInput.files[0];
      this.logo = file; 
}
```

And error is

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 422, statusText: "Unprocessable Entity", url: "myUrl", ok: false, …}
error:
messages: ["The logo field is required."]
status: false
__proto__: Object
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for url: 422 Unprocessable Entity"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 422
statusText: "Unprocessable Entity"
url: "url"
```

I send this object to api

```
{first_name: "Firts Name", last_name: "Last Name", email: "a@gmail.com", phone: "+923045203200", password: "03045203200", …}
    accounting_method: "Cash"
    business_location: [{…}]
    business_location_name: "myLegalBusiness"
    business_name: "myLegalBusiness"
    business_phone: "0304520320055"
    business_system_name: "tradeName"
    confirm_p: "03045203200"
    currency: "ALL"
    currency_id: 1
    ein_ssn: "EIN34"
    email: "asad@gmail.com"
    first_name: "Firts Name"
    fy_end_month: "MARCH"
    last_name: "Last Name"
    logo: File {name: "users.png", lastModified: 1561615773639, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jun 27 2019 11:09:33 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 2550, …}
    number_of_stores: 1
    password: "03045203200"
    phone: "+923045203200"
    store_name: "store"
    store_type: "Franchise"
    unique_code: "145dd" }
```

Comment: What error ? I didnt see any

Comment: I have updated the question please see again

Comment: And how you submit your logo ? Please add full code with your api code

Comment: I have added the final object which i send to api but i don't have api code please help me to identify is there any error in my side or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to send incorrect entity or data into the image attribute. In angular file events should be captured using

> this.logo  = imageInput.target.files[0]

This is a modified code for all cases, try using this. If you want image link (file Path) use imgLink or if you are sending the imageData use imgData.Consider the html file

```
<input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event)">
```

and the Ts file

```
imgLink         : any 
imgData         : any

selectFile(event) {

    this.imgLink = ''

    this.imgData  = event.target.files[0]

    //In your case
    this.logo = this.imgData

    let mimeType  = this.imgData.type

    if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
      const message = "This file type is not supported, Please upload in image format"
      return
    }

    let reader = new FileReader() 
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.imgData)
    reader.onload = (event) => { 
      this.imgLink = reader.result
    }
  }
```

Comment: what should i pass to api imgLink or imgData?

Comment: imgData @MalikAsad

Answer (score 1):

You can use **formData** for it.

```
onFileChanged(imageInput: any) {

  let fi = imageInput;

  if (fi.files && fi.files[0]) {

    let fileToUpload = fi.files[0];

    let formData: FormData = new FormData();

    formData.append("file", fileToUpload);

    formData.append('first_name', "Firts Name");
    formData.append('email', "a@gmail.com");
    formData.append('logo', {name: "users.png", lastModified: 1561615773639, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jun 27 2019 11:09:33 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 2550, …});
    ...

    console.log(formData)

}
```

Comment: but how i add my other json data?

Comment: `formData.append('first_name', "Firts Name");`

Comment: You need to append that as well: `{name: "users.png", lastModified: 1561615773639, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jun 27 2019 11:09:33 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 2550, …}`

Comment: i have appended this info in logo please see this 
formData.append("logo", logo); logo = File {name: "users.png", lastModified: 1561615773639, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jun 27 2019 11:09:33 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 2550, …}

Answer (score 0):

You can send images through `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`.you have to change the API to accept the `'multipart/form-data'. then only you can upload images.

this is the method to do

`const frmData = new FormData();`
`frmData.append("name", "name");`
`frmData.append("file","imageUrl");`

`const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      "enctype": "multipart/form-data"
    });`

`const options = {
      headers: httpHeaders
    };`

`return this.http.post<string>( "/URL", frmData, options);`